# What motivated the terms 'ergative' and 'absolutive'?

Tags: terminology, cases, ergativity

<sub>Source: p 195, *Understanding Syntax* (4 ed, 2014) by Prof. Maggie Tallerman PhD in Linguistics [(U. Hull)](http://www.ncl.ac.uk/elll/staff/profile/maggie.tallerman)</sub>

> ERGATIVE is the case of A – the subject of transitive verbs. ABSOLUTIVE is the case of both S and O, the subject of intransitive verbs and the object of transitive verbs.

I understand the definitions above, but what motivated linguists to choose these terms to describe the above cases for this Morphosyntactic Alignment? I am conjecturing the word choice not to be random, and know that ['ergative'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ergative) originates from Greek and ['absolutive'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=absolute) from the Latin *absolvere*.

Comment: See also https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/43937/9781

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the Intro Syntax textbook, the statement is biased; or, if you prefer, it's a category error.

In a case system that uses *Ergative* and *Absolutive* case names, there is no such thing as a "subject" or "object". It's precisely equivalent to the statement

- OBJECT is the case of A – the absolutive of transitive verbs. SUBJECT is the case of both A and E, the absolutive of intransitive verbs and the ergative of transitive verbs.

In other words, ergative/absolutive systems don't normally have a category "subject", just as
nominative/accusative systems don't normally have a useful category "absolutive". Every clause has a subject in one system, and every clause has an absolutive in the other; and in both systems there are specialized cases that occur only with transitive verbs.

As for the etymologies, ***ergative*** comes from the same Greek root as *energy*; with transitive verbs, the ergative is normally the agent (prototypically human), and in many languages this is generalized to a mark of agency or volitionality with various verb classes and constructions.

***Absolutive***, on the other hand, is a generalized replacement for many other  earlier names, including *nominative*, for the most common, default case in an ergative/absolutive system, which, besides being theoretically "the unmarked case", is often actually unmarked.  Some preferred *nominative* because in split-ergative systems like most Pama-Nyungan languages, where the nouns use an ergative/absolutive system while the pronouns use a nominative/accusative one, the same morpheme often shows up as both absolutive with nouns and nominative with pronouns.

Comment: +1. Thank you. 1. To which book do you refer with `the Intro Ling textbook`? The one stated in my OP? 2. Will you please explain why **absolutive** was chosen `a generalized replacement for many other earlier names`? What is **absolutive** about this case? In what meaning is this case **absolutive**? Does its etymology connect with its meaning here?

Comment: Would you please respond in your answer, which is easier to read than comments?

Comment: You say `subject' and `object' have no meaning in an ergative system, then you proceed to say what they mean in such a system.  If they don't mean anything, how can you tell us what they mean?  This is puzzling.

Comment: Sorry; I didn't recheck the title. It sounded like an intro ling book. Greg, I meant that the sentence quoted and the one I matched with it are equally category mistakes. Neither is particularly helpful in understanding how an ergative system works.